# Files in Visiual Studio goes excluded while switching branch and git pull origin

Tags: git, visual-studio

Files in Visiual Studio goes excluded while switching branch and git pull origin.
the files remains present but not shown up and are shown as excluded files.
Like the Infrastructure folder etc.what is the reason for git behaving like that, the files are shown by clicking on show all files.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that someone else changed the state of these files on the remote and you simply pulled those changes in.

Comment: How someone has changed their states.We in team if don't touch other files then this also happens.

Comment: Does `excluded` mean the file is no longer being tracked by Git?

Comment: No it present, but problems come that excluded controller files apis are not called on dev server, and then we have to see all folders that if some file maybe not included.

Comment: What kind of project is this? Is this one of the "magic" project types that just grabs all the files in the folder, or is it one of the project types where the project file contains an explicit list of all the files the project contains? If the latter, couldn't it simply be that someone removed the files from the project file?

Comment: It is web api project developed in c#